# UWP FullTrustProcess can't load dll

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

I'm using uwp and winforms project as full trust process. In winF project I've added reference through NuGet to Dotras.dll. Dll was added to references and everything look ok, launching from winforms directly works good. 
But when launching UWP and fullTrustProcess called (connection is ok, messages sended) and trying to call Dotras.dll exception thrown.

> Could not load file or assembly 'DotRas, Version=1.3.5166.33435, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b378f04384b7892a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've tried adding refernce to UWP project, but it it not allowing cause target is .net core and DotRas is .net framework.
Any hints where to put dll to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the exe and dll are deployed to the same folder.

Here is how.

Open the project in Visual Studio, there is an `Assets` folder, normally it is used to store logo images.

Put both exe and dll into this folder, by right clicking the folder, and select "Add New Item" in the menu, and set their `Build Action` as `Content`, so during app deployment they will be to copied to the installation directory in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\YouPackageFamilyName\`, under the same `Assets` folder.

In the appxmanifest file, make sure the executable path is correct.

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Assets\YourWinForms.exe">
</desktop:Extension>
```

**Edit:** It doesn't have to be the Assets folder, the key is add the dll to the project with `Build Action` set as `Content` and put in the same folder as the exe.

Comment: wrong. `Dotras.dll` is a .net **framework** library. You can't load it in UWP project because it is .net **core** project.

Comment: it is not referencing the dll, it is "adding new item", you can add pretty any file to a project as long as its `Build Action` is `Content`.

Comment: sure you can. With the same result you can create an empty text file and rename it to "Dotras.dll". The exception is throwing because application is trying to **load** `Dotras.dll`, so if you add it, `FileNotFoundException` will be replaced with `BadImageException`. How can this be helpful?

Comment: Maybe you have not tried [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/12/19/desktop-bridge-the-migrate-phase-invoking-a-win32-process-from-a-uwp-app/), this is an approach to invoke win32 applications from within UWP, much like Process.Start it will spawn a new process, this is the context of this question. The dll is not loaded into the process of the UWP app, it is loaded into the separate WinForm process, so no `BadImageException` is thrown.

Comment: oh, I see now, you where right, I'm sorry for misleading comments